# What is the use of self.width in the Line Instruction of the Canvas Widget of Kivy library in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am following a freeCodeCamp course on Kivy by Jonathan Roux, and I have came across a point which he didn't explain well. That is the self.width in the Line instruction. What is it used for and what does it mean?

Code Written (.kv file):

```
<CanvasWidget1@Widget>
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.center_x-s/2, self.center_y-s/2
        size: s, s
    Ellipse:
        pos: 200, 500
        size: s, s/2
    Line:
        points: (0, 0, self.width/4, 100, self.width/2, 0, self.width*3/4, 100, self.width, 0)
```

Comment: In `kvlang` the keyword `self` references the [current widget instance](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords), here `CanvasWidget1`. So it's `width` of that widget.

Comment: How much of the width does the CanvasWidget1 take?

Comment: That completely depends on relative usage. In other words, it can not be said without seeing the actual implementation.